# IRS ACA Webservice : Invalid GZIP compressed request

Tags: web-services

I am getting invalid GZIP Compressed request error. I have used apache cxf and wss4j.

I have explicitly set the transfer encoding and contentype in datahandler. I can see that content-Type is set correctly in the outgoing message but content-transfer-encoding still shows binary whereas I want it to be 7bit. I think this is what causing this error. Here is excerpt of the code.

```
try {
        ACABulkRequestTransmitterType bulkRequest = new ACABulkRequestTransmitterType();
        URL bulkFileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("1094B_Request_BB01V_20151202T010102000Z.xml");      
        ConfigurableDataHandler dataHandler = new ConfigurableDataHandler(bulkFileUrl);     
        dataHandler.setTransferEncoding("7bit");
        dataHandler.setContentType("application/xml");
        bulkRequest.setBulkExchangeFile(dataHandler);               

        client.invoke("BulkRequestTransmitter", bulkRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is soap attachment looks like:

--uuid:3bdbf1ac-8a39-4a66-b4c5-0312046d9b8d
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <5e3d2000-1895-425f-994a-8137ebf17ea3-1@urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common>
Content-Disposition: attachment;name="1094B_Request_BB01V_20151202T010102000Z.xml"

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I had to do this.

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPOutInterceptor.useGzip",
               "YES");
```